# Which are the best Java API for convert docx to pdf

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, itext, doc

I need an API java for convert a docx to pdf, I tested with  XDocReport but  I believe this doesn't convert the image of the head of the document.I need convert table,image and border in the pdf,the api can be paid or free.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: XDocReport can manage image in the head document, but perhaps you have a case which is very complex? Please create an issue by attaching your docx.

Comment: You could try our (commercial) converter at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few years ago I have successfully used JODConverter with Open Office running in the headless mode to convert all sorts of files.

To be honest I cannot remember the exact limitations of the software, but there is a version of what I did still running as a webservice here:

http://oxgarage.oucs.ox.ac.uk:8080/ege-webclient/

and here: http://www.tei-c.org/oxgarage/.

No idea about what is the current version of the converter they are using and it is possible that it is a bit outdated and at the moment it works a lot better, but you can try to convert your files and see how well they come up before you go head first into coding.

I also found this article and it looks like it might be quite helpful for you, have a look at it:

http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/how-to-convert-docxodt-to-pdfhtml-with-java/.

Oh and by the way, that webservice is opensource:

https://github.com/sebastianrahtz/oxgarage
, so you can have a look at how it is implemented as well.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you try JODconverter
https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/